# Images not centred

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stzfQ.png)

I am new to HTML and CSS, and I am trying to center these images, I can margin them from left to specific pixels but I think there should be a better solution.
I was googling for two days and I was trying to solve it but I can't find any solution.

Don't know what else should I write here. I am self-studying with online courses.

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  color:#000;
}
h3{
  color: #000
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bonheur+Royale&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: "Bonheur Royale" ,cursive ;
  margin: 0px
}
body h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}
#main-header {
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
#top-stories {
  width: 1000px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
article {
  max-width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.article-image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header" >
  <h1>Welcome in my new page! </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="top-stories">
    <article>
      <div class="article-image" style="background:url(/Users/jozefdzogan/Desktop/atom/images/iu.jpeg)"> </div>
      <h3> Dog </h3>
      <p> Text abou some dog i dont know </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="article-image" style="background:url(/Users/jozefdzogan/Desktop/atom/images/1344352035229.jpg)"></div>
      <h3> My old helmet </h3>
      <p>Some text goes in here </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <div class="article-image" style="background:url(/Users/jozefdzogan/Desktop/atom/images/23289271.jpg)"></div>
      <h3> AIC steelwork <a href="#">More </a>  now </h3>
      <p> html </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your `#top-stories` add the following css:

```css
#top-stories {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Above only works if you are using `display: flex`.

If you want equal spacing between your divs, consider `justify-content: space-between` and `justify-content: space-around;`

If you are NOT using flex:

```css
#top-stories{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I tried it without flex and with inline-block and text-align center and it doesn't work, but first one is working

Comment: Try it with display: block

Comment: didn’t work either, but first one is good enough for me, it was bugging me for two days and i’m happy i finally solved it with your help. there is still a lot to learn for me

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve exactly? Your image is set as a background with size cover and position center. This means the image will fill the entire div and be aligned to the center of the div. As supposed to align to left, right, top, etc...

If you use the img tag instead of background you can center the image both horizontally and vertically if you like using display flex as the other answer suggested.

```
.article-image {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}


<article>

        <div class="article-image"> 
<!-- Here is how you would use the img tag instead of setting it with background--->
        <img src="/Users/jozefdzogan/Desktop/atom/images/iu.jpeg"></div>
        <h3> Dog </h3>
        <p> Text abou some dog i dont know </p>
      </article>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it was just an online lesson and it didn’t work for me to center the images. normally i would use img tag as you suggested.